# How can I find a HTML tag with the pseudoElement ::before in jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, pseudo-element

I will read the img links from a website with jsoup. When I search the HTML code I find the links in a ::before
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) element like

```
::before 
<span>
<img src="https://link.png" alt=""> 
</span>
```

My Java Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JavaApplication6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String link = "https://www.panasonic.com/de/consumer/foto-video/lumix-kompaktkameras/dmc-lx100.html";

            Document docHauptseite = Jsoup.connect(link)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .get();


            Elements sImages = docHauptseite.getElementsByClass("thumb-block");
            System.out.println("sImages count = " + sImages.size());

            Elements sImagesFeatures = docHauptseite.getElementsByClass("featureslide650image");
            System.out.println("sImagesFeatures count = " + sImagesFeatures.size());



    }
}
```

I got no results in the class="thumb-block". If I look at the HTML code i can see:

```
<div class="thumb-block">
::before
    <span>
        <img src="https:link" alt="DMC-LX100 Premium-Kompaktkamera Bild für Miniaturansicht 2">
    </span>
</div>
```

In the jsoup result I got no tags which starts with the ::before element. Has anyone an idea, how I can fix this with jsoup?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please post some code, how you search the html with jsoup. To do so, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I read some more informations.

The content is added to the html-code by JavaScript. Jsoup don't support JavaScript. So it is not possible with Jsoup.

I will try it with an other tool like Selenium.

Thank you.